# Despite using virtual environment base interpreter is called

Tags: python, django

Using: `django 1.2`, `python 2.7`, windows 7.

When calling `manage.py` from terminal with virtual environment activated, I get `import error` for `django` modules.

This is as the wrong interpreter is being used-the `python27` interpreter in root directory (when directly running `python.exe` in the virtual environment, `import django...` is successful).

Why is this happening? I thought virtual environments prevent use of anything external. How do I override this behaviour and get it to use the `python27\virtualenv\django12env\scripts\python.exe` to run `manage.py`?

EDIT: I ran `virtualenv --no-site-packages -p C:\python27\virtualenvs\django12env\scripts\python.exe` ad got back `Running virtualenv with interpreter C:\python27\virtualenvs\django12\scripts\python.exe Using real prefix 'C:\\Python27' New python executable in django12env\Scripts\python.exe Installing setuptools`

However it still isn't using the interpreter I want.

I also don't understand why virtual environment would use an external interpreter in the first place, rather than the interpreter it installs.

Answer (score -1):

Virtual Environments for python were not meant to give you a complete sandbox from the rest of your libraries. If you want to use your own interpreter and its libraries, then pass the --no-site-packages flag to your virtualenv command (optionally passing in the absolute path to the interpreter you want to use)

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages -p C:\python27\bin\python.exe django12env
```

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

EDIT: For comment responses
Virtualenv actually didn't originally come with --no-site-packages option. It was intended to allow developers to easily manage projects and their associated apps and versions without mucking up the system path or manage sets of PYTHONPATH for each project. The interpreter was envisioned to be utilized across the entire system.

As far as you wanting to use a different interpreter all together, my advice would be to download the python distributable that you would like, set your pytyhon path on the command line, install setuptools and pip and virtualenv with that interpreter.

```
set PYTHONPATH=C:\venvs\django12\python26\;C:\venvs\django12\python26\Scripts
```

Download ez_setup.py
https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py

```
C:\venvs\django12\python26\python.exe C:\Downloads\ez_setup.py

C:\venvs\django12\python26\Scripts\easy_install pip
C:\venvs\django12\python26\Scripts\pip install virtualenv

C:\venvs\django12\python26\Scripts\virtualenv --no-site-packages .
```

And then finish installing your apps. I hope this helps.

Comment: check your pip freeze list.  Did you actually install django to the venv?

Comment: Ran `virtualenv --no-site-packages -C:\python27\virtualenvs\django12env\scripts\python.exe`. Get back `Running virtualenv with interpreter C:\Programming\Python27\virtualEnvs\Django12\Scri
pts\python.exe
Using real prefix 'C:\\Python27'
New python executable in django12env\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools...` Still uses base interpreter.

Comment: @joel goldstick Yes, Django 1.2 is installed at `C:\Python27\virtualEnvs\Django12env\Lib\site-packages`.

Comment: Also whats the logic of defaulting virtualenv interpreter to a base interpreter? Isn't the single point of virtualenvs in fact to create a clean sandbox environment? It after all does replicate a global install with an in house interpreter so why then try to go back outside of that?

Comment: are you sure you are running in your virtual environment?

Comment: @joel goldstick I'm not sure you're making any genuine attempt at help as both of your counter questions are already answered in my question. Yes, the virtual environment is activated. My specific problem is that the base interpreter is being called instead of the virtualenv interpreter, even when I try to specify otherwise in the command line.

Comment: Have you set your PYTHONPATH to the new interpreter and scripts?